# Make div 100% width with equal margins on both sides of content area

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'm wanting to do. When the site gets down to medium and small sizes, I want 100% width with margin: 20px all around. I'm trying to not define specific pixels for the width, so that it's consistent across all devices as much as possible. I figured that my CSS would apply the 20px margin to the right side as well as the left, but it's only applying to the left and the right is going outside the window.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="swipe-content">
    <div id="your-accounts">
        <h1>Your Accounts</h1>
        <p>
            Your accounts data will go here.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.swipe-content {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Sorry to waste anyone's time with this, but it's late and I'm probably missing something really simple. I'm coming back to coding after a couple of years and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS when you specify a width, it usually means the inner-width not the outer-width.

outer-width = inner-width + margin + padding + border

In your case, your div is becoming 100% + 20px (left padding) + 20 px (right padding)

When you add `display: block`, the div will automatically try to take up as much width as possible.

Sure, in CSS 3 you could take advantage of the box-sizing property as focorner suggested. But to be compatible i would suggest removing `width: 100%` and adding `display: block`.

For this to work, you would need an outer div which has 100% width and is `display:block`

**TL;DR**

```
{
display: block;
// width: 100%; remove this
padding: 20px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple option would be to use:

```
.swipe-content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by creating an outer div that fills the entire page and setting it to have a left and right padding of both 20px.

You could then put a div on the inside that fits 100% of the outer div.

```
#outer {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;

    background-color: grey;  
}
```

Here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/SplashHero/cb1xs67u/

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
.swipe-content { 
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin : 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```